# Tree growth curve for each season?

Tags: trees

Is there a record as to general growth rate for tall trees in north east US grow? Oak, maple, etc.

I'd like to plot out how fast in general a tree will grow each year and have a guide for it. I'm very particular about data here :)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It will depend substantially on the specific location ; sun , soil type, moisture , nutrients , competition , etc. I had an oak in a good location grow from 1 "  to 18" diameter in about 20 years, ( about 1" per year), I am sure that is faster that references predict.

Comment: This might be a good question for [data.se].

Comment: The International Society of Arboriculture states "Tree growth rates are affected tremendously by conditions such as water availability, climate, soil conditions, root stress, competition for light, and overall plant vigor. Further, the growth rates of species within genera can vary significantly." There isn't just a single number like "Maples grow two feet per year on average." In addition, different cultivars of the same genus have different growth rates (Autumn Blaze Maple vs. Sugar Maple Green Mountain vs Burgundy Belle Maple all have different approx/avg growth rates).